# Stop Entity Framework from updating edmx model with a column that isn't needed

Tags: entity-framework, edmx, ef-database-first

I have rowguids in all my tables to help with change tracking in all my tables. I don't want/need these tables in my edmx or my entities. However, I do still need to make changes to other things sometimes so everytime i go to update model from database in the edmx it adds all the rowguids in all my tables everytime and i have to manually delete each one. Is there a way to handle this from happening? Is there a way I can maybe edit the T4 to maybe ignore that 'rowguid' column?

Database first Entity framework

Comment: do you want to prevent it from being in the edmx entirely? or just prevent it from being in the entities?

Comment: id like it to be both if possible

Comment: to also confirm, it sounds like it, but this is a DB first implementation correct?

Comment: yes sorry bout that. I'll update the question to note that

Comment: If you're using Database-First, then why do you have the Code-First tag on your question?

Comment: Ooops. Sorry about that. Thanks Krillgar

Comment: Hi @TMan, was there any solution found for this? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to intrinsically tell the edmx to not pull certain columns.  Because you want to prevent it in both the entities AND the edmx, altering the T4 template will not help you prevent it from being added to the edmx.

If you change your mind you could certainly prevent entities with a certain naming convention from being added in the T4. I prefer to keep my edmx files clean, and manually deleting is the only way I know to remove unwanted columns.

For others who may be interested in understanding EF T4 here's a basic article that I've found helpful in better understanding what it does and how it works:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx

To your question about generating a scrub script: edmx files behind the scenes are just xml markup trees. Every element shown in the viewer corresponds to one or more element in the tree. Here is a simple example of what the xml might look like for a simple Program entity.

If you wanted to scrub specific columns you could remove them from the underlying xml.

```
    <EntityType Name="Program">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="ProgramName" Type="varchar" MaxLength="150" />
      <Property Name="DateTimeCreated" Type="datetime" />
    </EntityType>
```

Sadly, this is not all you would also need to edit there are two locations in the edmx this and the conceptual model. you might also have to remove associations if they reference the deleted property.

You will also need to edit the msl.  I was hoping to mock up a personal example, but in lieu of that I have found two articles that discuss or examine the process others have gone through for this.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e61192da-8c51-4f17-8745-c4455c836f9d/ef-modify-csdl-ssdl-and-mapping-in-code-and-then-save-in-the-csdl-ssdl-files?forum=adodotnetentityframework

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2007/12/07/how-to-use-your-existing-csdl-msl-ssdl-files-in-the-entity-designer-ctp2.aspx

These two might give you a better idea of what's involved in that process.  It might still be worth it for you if it's a severe use case.

Comment: Hmmm, well then would it be possible to write a script to run against the edmx to maybe remove the column i wonder?

Comment: probably, if you inspect the .edmx file in Notepad++ or even in VS, it's just a very specific xml markup tree, with a viewer.  give me a few and i'll se if i can dig up an example and add some stuff that might help in this regard, to my answer

Comment: hmmm, as i dug in i'm remembering this is usually a mistake, i'm still going to try to address it, may take me a bit longer.

Answer (score -1):

If there are tables you do not want in your .edmx or entities, then don't select them when you create the entity data models.

When creating the entity data model in the wizard, go for "EF Designer from Database" (database first).

To get there, right click the solution -> Add -> New Item... -> Under the 'Data' category, select a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model -> 'EF Designer from Database'

After the connection settings prompt, make sure you ***only*** include the tables you want.

[image]

Comment: The question mentions problems with extra columns getting added each time the EF is synced with the database. This only solves the problem if unnecessary tables were added to the model.